# How to Add Analytic account in Purchase Picking report

Tags: field, odoo-8, qweb

I tried to integrate the analytic account in report.picking for purchase, like I've done for sale.
For sale picking report i have done like this :

```
<span class="oe_editable" t-field="o.sale_id.project_id"/>
```

I tried to do the same in picking report for incoming  like that:

```
<t t-if="o.picking_type_id.code !== 'outgoing'">
    <td>
       <span class="oe_editable" t-field="o.sale_id.project_id"/>
    </td>
</t>
<t t-if="o.picking_type_id.code !== 'incoming'">
    <td>
        <span class="oe_editable" t-field="o.invoice_line[0].account_analytic_id"/>
    </td>
</t>
```

I have got an error like:

> QWebException: "'stock.picking' object has no attribute 'invoice_line'" while evaluating
>       'o.invoice_line[0]'

But I can't find the right field to integrate.

I think I don't have the good model in `o.*`

Any idea on how the find good and complete field name ?